# Linux - How to upload file via download streaming?

Tags: linux, shell

A - Client storage: 1GB (CentOS)

F - File size: 10GB (Ex: http://www.ex.com/File.zip)

B - Server path upload: http://www.server.com/upload.php

How to upload F (File.zip) to B (Server) by A (Client) without store file?
or Split "File.zip" to multi parts for continue upload?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
curl http://www.ex.com/File.zip | curl --form "bigfile=@-" http://www.server.com/upload.php
```

Comment: I am tested but It download completed then upload, not upload same time. Client not enough space:(